# system_profiler applications inventory

Tags: system-information

Running this:

```
system_profiler -detailLevel full
```

produces an inventory of applications, among other things.

How does they system "know" about these apps?

- Spotlight? (e.g. every time a folder is created/renamed with the .app extension..)
- searching the filesystem at the moment of invocation? (e.g. `find -type d -name '*.app'` ...)
- scanning predefined paths?
- other?

Would stopping the md service affect the output? Restoring from TimeMachine?

What I'd ultimately like to do is to *query* this "database", if it is a db and not some "just-in-time" query.

Useful queries:

- Scan for outdated/insecure downloads of application X, if version >= Y
- Is uTorrent present anywhere?
- Does this system have PPC applications on it still?
- etc.

Comment: Where exactly in the output are you talking about finding the list of apps? Can you provide a snippet? So I can match up my query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running `opensnoop` while running the `system_profiler` command.

I just did that, and with the full detail level as you have it there are over 25,000 files that are being read by system_profiler. It looks like it is reading plist files to get the output as well as reproducing various system logs.

If you stop md or restore from TimeMachine the output will change.